# Ruby - string to float giving no decimals

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert coordinates from string to float, but it's not giving me decimals after `,`  in string. What am I missing?

```
latitude = "45,815272"
longitude = "16,23"
```

After `to_f`:

```
latitude.to_f => 45.0
longitude.to_f => 16.0
```

Comment: @Rajagopalan's answer works, but you might not know why. Ruby assumes the convention (used in English-speaking world, and Japan where Ruby originated) that decimals are separated by a point, not a comma. Commas are ambiguous as they're also used in these countries to separate large numbers (so 1,000,000 in the UK is 1 million, not 1!). So any logic has to be done by hand, based on context. Also, to_f will try its hardest to give you an answer, so "123Foo".to_f will return 123.0, hence the behaviour you're observing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this

```
 longitude.gsub(",",".").to_f
```

Comment: `sub` is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, in this case!

Comment: It's always more efficient because `gsub` always has at least one extra iteration. `sub` is  not the appropriate method to use if you have to handle multiple replacements. Always remember there's reasons for similar methods and picking the right one can have big payoffs in memory and/or CPU use. Knowing which to use when is the goal.